'a' to 'c' were not declared in this scope
I have some trouble with my program called "Kalkulator ceny paliwa".
I have this code
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

using namespace std;

double benzyna(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

double diesel(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

double lpg(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

double cng(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

double wodor(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    int wyborPaliwa = 0;
    double dystans, avgSpalanie, cenaPaliwa, kosztPaliwa;
    
    
    cout << "Podaj rodzaj paliwa, na ktorym jezdzi Twoj samochod (1 - benzyna, 2 - olej napedowy, 3 - LPG, 4 - CNG, 5 - wodór): " << endl;
    
    switch(wyborPaliwa) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynoszą: " << benzyna(a,b,c) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
            
        case 2:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynoszą: " << diesel(a,b,c) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
            
        case 3:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynoszą: " << lpg(a,b,c) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
        
        case 4:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynoszą: " << cng(a,b,c) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
        
        case 5:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynoszą: " << wodor(a,b,c) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
    } 
    
    return 0;
}

And i'm getting these errors:
44  62  C:\Users\Antoni\Documents\Projekty C++\KalkulatorZuzyciaPaliwa\main.cpp [Error] 'a' was not declared in this scope
44  64  C:\Users\Antoni\Documents\Projekty C++\KalkulatorZuzyciaPaliwa\main.cpp [Error] 'b' was not declared in this scope
44  66  C:\Users\Antoni\Documents\Projekty C++\KalkulatorZuzyciaPaliwa\main.cpp [Error] 'c' was not declared in this scope

Where i've done the mistakes?
I'm beginner, so please do not hit me.
I hope that i will receive help
I want these errors, that i've written before gone.

benzyna(a,b,c) - you didn't define a, b or c.  The same applies to the other function calls.

Also all your functions expect 3 pointers to doubles and 1 double. You don't pass matching arguments.

OT: Why are your function using pointers as arguments? Why are you passing kosztPaliwa as an argument? Please take some time to refresh your beginners material about variables, functions, passing arguments, and returning values.

I corrected it.
Now i don't receiving the result of calculated fuel.

int wyborPaliwa = 0; That's the only place you set the value of wyborPaliwa. Your switch doesn't have a case for it being zero.

Okay guys. Now i tried without pointers. Now works perfeclty.
Thank you for help

@Someprogrammerdude i just add also default value for this switch. I will also take time to refresh this knowledge that you written before

I suggest getting a good book. You appear to be trying to fix errors by guessing. I've been there and I do not give that experience a rousing endorsement.

@Chris thank you for suggestions. I'm going to purchase a book in polish language like "Opus Magnum C++" by Jerzy Grebosz.

@gryc3k get the newest edition you can. There appears to be editions for both C++11 and C++14/17. The latter is probably the better bet.

"'a' was not declared in this scope" -- This is your first error. The message is simple enough, so a useful tactic (for both debugging and writing a question) is to argue with your compiler. Explain either 1) where a is declared in this scope or 2) why a does not need to be declared. (In case you need a reference for "this scope": the first two numbers tell you where this particular a occurs: line 44, character 62.)

A [mre] makes it easier to spot an error (focus on the first error). For "not declared in this scope", that means removing almost everything other than the line in question and the definitions of things mentioned in that line. For example: `#include  double benzyna(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) { /* processing omitted */ return 0.0; }
int main() {
std::cout << benzyna(a,b,c); }At this level of brevity, it becomes rather easy to see that there is no definition ofa`, right?

You are worried about memory.  All the functions are the same.  Get rid of all but one.

Don't modify a parameter with the return value.  Return a value or modify a parameter, not both.

When using numbers, use a ".0" to convert to double precision, example: dystans / 100.0.

Looks like the cases have a lot of duplication.  Move the duplicate statements to before the case statement and only call the appropriate function in each case. Do not Repeat Yourself (DRY).  You can also move statements after the function calls to after the end of the switch statement.

Side note: Don't use variable names like a, b, and c.They are non-descriptive, and tell the reader nothing about what the variable means or how it should be used. This makes it harder to spot bugs in code. Example c = a + b; could be right or it could be adding the wrong variables and assigning to one of the variables that should have been added. result  = operand_left + operand_right; can be read to confirm correctness.

@ThomasMatthews i understand you, but i want to make an options of choosing a fuel type to calculate the cost of driving route for every fuel type that i've written

@chris according to book, i want to buy but i'm broke

You are on a rough road then, my friend. Among the free books, this is king, but it is very stale at this point and terse as all hell, usable more for upgrading existing knowledge than learning from scratch. The tutorial site Learncpp.com is also good. Perhaps the two resources in combination will put you on a better path.

@user4581301
I'll try also polish video tutorial series C++ coding on Pasja Informatyki channel.
I'm still making errors and mistakes despite trying a lot. Shall i give up or not?

Never give up! Never surrender! Do what you can to get good resources and keep learning. C++ is very likely the most complicated programming language in wide use today, and it takes a LONG time to get good at it. There are parts of C++ that I still rarely use in production code because I don't understand them well enough to explain what I've done to the rest of my team.


Add the cin command to let user put in the value for wyborPaliwa right
before Switch statement, that would be used by Switch statment to call its
corresponding case. Without it the case 0 will be run that acutally
doesn't exist.
Change the a, b, c to dystans, avgSpalanie, cenaPaliwa respectively.
Pass there addresses that would be stored in the receiving pointers.
i.e. &dystans.
Pass the kosztPaliwa variable as 4th argument without using '&' as the
receiver is not the pointer.
Add the default case at the very last of Switch bracket.

Note: Working with pointers would be done with extra precautions as the real memory is at the stake. If anything bad happens, the actual data would be courrputed or lost.
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double benzyna(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

double diesel(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

double lpg(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

double cng(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

double wodor(double* dystans, double* avgSpalanie, double* cenaPaliwa, double kosztPaliwa) {
    return kosztPaliwa = ((*dystans)/100) * (*avgSpalanie) * (*cenaPaliwa);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    int wyborPaliwa = 0;
    double dystans, avgSpalanie, cenaPaliwa, kosztPaliwa;
    
    
    cout << "Podaj rodzaj paliwa, na ktorym jezdzi Twoj samochod (1 - benzyna, 2 - olej napedowy, 3 - LPG, 4 - CNG, 5 - wodór): " << endl;

    cin>> wyborPaliwa;
    
    switch(wyborPaliwa) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynosza: " << benzyna(&dystans,&avgSpalanie,&cenaPaliwa, kosztPaliwa) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
            
        case 2:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynosza: " << diesel(&dystans,&avgSpalanie,&cenaPaliwa, kosztPaliwa) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
            
        case 3:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynosza: " << lpg(&dystans,&avgSpalanie,&cenaPaliwa, kosztPaliwa) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
        
        case 4:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynosza: " << cng(&dystans,&avgSpalanie,&cenaPaliwa, kosztPaliwa) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
        
        case 5:
            cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
            cin >> dystans;
            cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
            cin >> avgSpalanie;
            cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
            cin >> cenaPaliwa;
            cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynosza: " << wodor(&dystans,&avgSpalanie,&cenaPaliwa, kosztPaliwa) << "zl" << endl;
        break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid choice. Please select a valid option." << endl;
            return 1;
    } 
    
    return 0;
}


There is no reason to pass by address.  The double type can be passed via registers and the copy operation is not slow.  If a parameter will be modified by a function, pass by reference.  Avoid pointers as much as possible.

Agree. Only the syntactical and logical mistakes are resolved being in the same programming approach and design. The poster is a beginner and will learn to do it in a better way. It can be optimised further.

Since there is a lot of duplication in your program, you could simplify it to:
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int wyborPaliwa    = 0;
    double dystans     = 0.0;
    double avgSpalanie = 0.0;
    double cenaPaliwa  = 0.0;
    double kosztPaliwa = 0.0;
    
    static const char text_menu[] =
        "Podaj rodzaj paliwa, na ktorym jezdzi Twoj samochod\n"            
        "(1 - benzyna\n"
        " 2 - olej napedowy\n"
        " 3 - LPG\n"
        " 4 - CNG\n"
        " 5 - wodór):\n";
    cout.write(text_menu, sizeof(text_menu));
    cin >> wyborPaliwa;

    cout << "Podaj dystans do przejechania: ";
    cin >> dystans;
    cout << "Podaj srednie spalanie twojego samochodu: ";
    cin >> avgSpalanie;
    cout << "Podaj cene benzyny za litr na Twojej stacji: ";
    cin >> cenaPaliwa;
    cout << "Koszty przejechania trasy wynosza: ";

    const double result = 
        (dystans / 100.0)
        * avgSpalanie
        * cenaPaliwa;
    cout << result << "zl" << endl;
 
    return 0;
}

There is no reason for #include <math.h> because you don't use anything declared in that header file.  Multiplication, division, addition and subtraction come standard and don't need a header file.
I eliminated the functions because they are all the same. The internal code of the functions is pasted after the input of the values.
Since the calculations are all the same, I removed the switch statement.  The menu could also be eliminated.
This eliminates your errors with passing variables to functions since the functions are removed.

Moreover, if you are using the C math library in C++, include <cmath>.

@Chris i wanted to make an option of selection the fuel type. I'm begginner so i hqve right to make mistakes and not understaning more complicated code

@Thomas Matthews i understand your solution. but what's this text_menu? I don't reached the arrays yet

Since your output string doesn't contain any formatting (like printing numbers), I made a const C-Style string.  C-Style strings are actually arrays of text with a terminating NUL character.  By making it an array, the compiler knows the length of the array (string).  Block writing is a fast way to display text.
